# How can I add an animated gif to a scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gif

In three.js, how can I add an animated gif?

```
var materialTextured = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/pin.gif'),
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 150), materialTextured);
    plane.position.x=250;
    plane.scale.x = 1;
    scene.add(plane);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know Three.js not support GIF texture, but you can convert the GIF file to video, then use the [VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture).

Meanwhile, the video file has a better compression than the GIF file, which will improve the Web performance.

Comment: Yes not supoorted gif but...

    var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
    annie = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); // texture, #horiz, #vert, #total, duration.
    var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: runnerTexture, side:THREE.DoubleSide,transparent: true, } );
    var runnerGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50, 1, 1);
    var runner = new THREE.Mesh(runnerGeometry, runnerMaterial);
    runner.position.set(-100,400,-2048);
    runner.scale.x = 6;
    runner.scale.y = 6;
    scene.add(runner);